Gulp install error - Bad signature error ,ssl3_get_key_exchange
I am trying to install gulp 3.9.1 and getting an error message Bad signature error
write EPROTO 101057795:error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature:openssl\crypto\rsa\rsa_sign.c:278:
101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2032:

here are the version I am using since its legacy project

how to sort this error ?
